# UITableView && UICollectionView in one controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to implement iPhone and iPad versions gracefully. They're essentially the same controller, but one the iPhone presents in a single column tableView and the iPad in a multi-column collectionView.

Here are the options I thought of:

1. One ViewController that asks for a different DataSource and different Delegate for tableView vs collectionView. I haven't thought this option all the way through. It does seem like it might get overly complicated.
2. One baseViewController and then 2 subclasses, one with a tableView and one with a collectionView. Similar to option #1 but using subclasses. Option #1 is cleaner, but this would be easier to implement.
3. Just use a collectionView for both, but use different UICollectionViewFlowLayouts. This was the last option I thought of and seems like by far the best option, but I'm wondering if there's a reason why #1 or #2 might be better.

Comment: You can also create two different viewcontrollers and push accordingly for iPhone and iPad, your second approach looks similar to this. But with optimized code

Comment: You can also use the same delegate methods to handle multiple UITableViews for example, and choose what to do based on which tableView instance is passed through the parameter.

Comment: I would prefer 3rd option as it will be easier to manage and understand.

Comment: Watch the iTunes U series presented by the awesome Paul Hegarty for Stanford University, but the older version for iOS 7 that deals in Objective C. In the series "Developing iOS 7 Apps for iPhone and iPad", in [Lecture 11 Table View and iPad](https://itunes.apple.com/au/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550) he presents a really simple method to prepare an app for transition from iPhone only to universal (i.e. including iPad) and using `UISplitViewController` class.

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up going with 1 UICollectionView, and IMO it works great.

I had to write conditionals for only 3 parts:

1. Returning different collectionViewFlowLayouts
2. Returning different sizes for `collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:`
3. Different layouts for `layoutSubviews` of the `UICollectionViewCell`

---

Being able to use the same `UICollectionViewCell` was a really big plus since I am implementing a number of buttons within the cell, and I didn't have to replicate delegates for exactly similar logic in a `UICollectionViewCell` AND a `UITableViewCell`.